# Probabilities manipulation $P(Z_1+Z_2=2,Z_1=1,Z_2=1)=P(Z_1=1,Z_2=1)$ with $Z_1,Z_2 \in \lbrace 1,2,3,4 \rbrace$ independent and uniform

Tags: probability, random-variable, uniform-distribution

I've two independent and uniform random variables  $Z_1,Z_2 \in \lbrace 1,2,3,4 \rbrace$. Can you tell me why the following equality is correct please?

$$
P(Z_1+Z_2=2,Z_1=1,Z_2=1)=P(Z_1=1,Z_2=1)
$$

Comment: The LHS is vague, what does it mean?

Comment: Hello @gunes do you mean that the notation is vague?

Comment: Yes @GennaroArguzzi

Comment: @gunes sorry there was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This holds even if the variables are neither independent nor uniform because the event $Z_1+Z_2=2$ does not add anything when the RVs are both $1$.

Comment: Yes, similar to that.

Comment: is it like writing the same event twice?

Comment: thank you very much